# loop for working with individual values in r

Tags: r, loops

Here is my small dataset.

```
Indvidual <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Parent1 <- c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", NA)
Parent2 <- c(NA, NA, "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", NA)
mydf <- data.frame (Indvidual, Parent1, Parent2)

  Indvidual Parent1 Parent2
1         A    <NA>    <NA>
2         B    <NA>    <NA>
3         C       A       B
4         D       A       C
5         E       C       D
6         F       C       D
7         G       C       D
8         H       E    <NA>
9         I       A       D
10        J      <NA>     <NA>
```

Just consider people who has two or one known parents. I need to compare and derieve score by calculating scores that their parents have.

The rules is that either one of parent (names in parent1 or parent2 column) is known (not NA), will  get 1 one additional score plus score their parents have. If there are two parents known, the highest scorer will be taken into consideration.

Here is an example:

```
Individual "A", has both parents unknown so will get score 0
Indiviudal "C", has both parents known (i.e. A, B) 
will get 0 score (maximum of their parents)
```

plus 1 (as it has either one of parents known)

Thus expected output from above dataframe (with explanation) is:

```
Indvidual Parent1 Parent2   Scores     Explanation 
1         A    <NA>    <NA>    0       0 (Max of parent Scores NA) + 0 (neither parent knwon) 
2         B    <NA>    <NA>    0       0 (Max of parent Scores NA)  + 0 (neither parent knwon) 
3         C     A       B      1    0 (Max of parent Scores)  +  1 (either parent knwon)       
4         D     A        C      2       1 (Max of parent scores)  +  1 (either parent knwon) 
5         E       C      D      3       2 (Max of parent scores) + 1 (either parent knwon)
6         F       C      D      3       2 (Max of parent scores) + 1 (either parent knwon)
7         G       C      D      3       2 (Max of parent scores) + 1 (either parent knwon)
8         H       E    <NA>     4       3 (Max of parent scores) + 1 (either parent knwon) 
9         I       A       D     3       2 (Max of parent scores) + 1 (either parent knwon)
10        J      <NA>    <NA>   0       0 (Max of parent scores NA)  + 0 (neither parent knwon)
```

Explanation: As loop goes on, it takes into account on the Scores already calculated. 
Max of parent scores

**Edits: based on chase's question**

For example:

```
Individual C has two parents A and B, each of which has Scores calculated as 0 and 0 
(in row 1 and 2 and column Scores),  means that max (c(0,0)) will be 0

Individual E has parents C and D, whose scores in Scores column is (in row 3 and 4),
 1 and 2, respectively.  So maximum of max(c(1,2)) will be 2.
```

Comment: can you explain what the "max of parent score" part means? At first, I thought this is what you needed, but I don't think that's the case: `rowSums(!is.na(mydf[,-1]))`

Comment: thanks Chase, see my recent edits, if makes a sense ....the idea is as we go down we calculate scores for each individual and if it happens to be parent then its score is used to calculate its son/ daughters scores.

Comment: Ahh, i get it now, the people who are "individuals" can also be the parents...ok - will think about this one. This is more clear now though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Individual <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Parent1 <- c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", NA)
Parent2 <- c(NA, NA, "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", NA)
mydf <- data.frame (Individual, Parent1, Parent2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mydf$Scores <- NA
mydf$Scores[rowSums(is.na(mydf[, c("Parent1", "Parent2")])) == 2] <- 0
while(any(is.na(mydf$Scores))){
  KnownScores <- mydf[!is.na(mydf$Scores), c(1, 4)]
  ToCalculate <- mydf[
    mydf$Parent1 %in% c(KnownScores$Individual, NA) & 
    mydf$Parent2 %in% c(KnownScores$Individual, NA) & 
    is.na(mydf$Scores), 
    -4]
  ToCalculate$Score <- apply(
    merge(
      merge(
        ToCalculate, 
        KnownScores, 
        by.x = "Parent1", 
        by.y = "Individual", 
        all.x = TRUE
      ), 
      KnownScores, 
      by.x = "Parent2",
      by.y = "Individual",
      all.x = TRUE
    )[, 4:5], 
    1, 
    max, 
    na.rm = TRUE) + 1
  mydf <- merge(mydf, ToCalculate[, c(1, 4)], all.x = TRUE)
  mydf$Scores[!is.na(mydf$Score)] <- mydf$Score[!is.na(mydf$Score)]
  mydf$Score <- NULL
}
```

Comment: I long this loop is expected to finsh in...I waited about 15 minutes and stopped running ...but loop doesnot stop...I am afraid what will happen to my big dataset....I am using RGui 64 bit ...is that expected ...

Comment: In fact the loop doesnot seem to end ...I am trying for 30 minutes

Comment: Did you copy-paste my code with the mydf data.frame or did you use another data.frame? Because I get an immediate result. If you use your own data, then there might be a problem with the data. E.g. parent which are not included as individuals. Run the loops manually and see is any ToCalculate$Score become NA

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just copy and pasted your whole solution in a fresh R session, now I manually run - the ToCalculate says that it has <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) !

Comment: I have spotted the problem. My code works if Individual, Parent1 and Parent2 are characters and not factors. The convertion is from character to factor is done automaticly unless options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE).

Answer (score 2):

Example using `plyr` and a recursive argument

```
library(plyr)
Indvidual <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
Parent1 <- c(NA, NA, "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "E", "A", NA)
Parent2 <- c(NA, NA, "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", NA, "D", NA)
mydf <- data.frame (Indvidual, Parent1, Parent2)
scor.fun<-function(x,mydf){
    Explanation<-0
    P1<-as.character(x$Parent1)
    P2<-as.character(x$Parent2)
    score<-as.numeric(!(is.na(P1)||is.na(P1)))
    if(!(is.na(P1)||is.na(P2))){
        Explanation<-max(scor.fun(subset(mydf,Indvidual==P1),mydf)[1],scor.fun(subset(mydf,Indvidual==P2),mydf)[1])
        score<-score+Explanation
    }else{
        Explanation<-ifelse(is.na(P1),0,scor.fun(subset(mydf,Indvidual==P1),mydf)[1])
        Explanation<-max(Explanation,ifelse(is.na(P2),0,scor.fun(subset(mydf,Indvidual==P2),mydf)[1]))
        score<-score+Explanation
    }
    c(score,Explanation)
}

adply(mydf,1,scor.fun,mydf)
```

Probably not the best idea with the recursion on a big dataframe.